# Atmosphere and spring portlet mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, asynchronous, portlet, atmosphere

It's possíble to use the recently released 1.0 version of the atmosphere framework with spring portlet mvc ? I have a portlet that makes multiple ajax calls and i would like to process them all in parallel in the server.

I'm using weblogic and the problem is that the server is queuing my requests. They are trully parallel when they leave the browser, but when they reach the server they are being enqueued.

What I would like is something similar to the assyncronous controller concept of spring 3.2 but in servlet 2.5 through the atmosphere framework